# I'm using Django ImageField but I can't access the images in my posts.html page

Tags: python, django, imagefield

I'm using ImageField in Django but when I try to access them in my html pages, it's not working. I tried to go through the previously asked questions that are kinda similar to mine but I couldn't understand the solutions.

Here is my model:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    sub_headline = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to="images", default="placeholder.png")
    body = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    featured = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, null=True)
```

Here is how am trying to access the images in posts.views

```
 {% for post in posts %}
        <div>
            <div class="post">
                <img class="thumbnail" src="{{post.thumbnail.url}}">
                <div class="post-preview">
                    <h6 class="post-title">{{post.headline}}</h6>
                    <p class="post-intro">{{post.sub_headline}}</p>
                    <a href="{% url 'post' post.id %}">Read More</a>
                    <hr>
                    {% for tag in post.tags.all %}
                        <span class="tag">{{tag}}, </span>
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        {% empty %}
            <h3 align="center">No posts found...</h3>
        {% endfor %}
```

**For more information:**

views.py

```
def posts(request):
    posts = Post.objects.filter(active=True)

    context = {'posts': posts}
    return render(request, 'base/posts.html', context)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name="home"),
    path('posts/', views.posts, name='posts'),
]
```

posts.html

```
{% extends 'base/main.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}

<div class="main-container">
    <h3 align="center">Posts</h3>
    <div class="post-wrapper">
        {% for post in posts %}
        <div>
            <div class="post">
                <img class="thumbnail" src="{{post.thumbnail.url}}">
                <div class="post-preview">
                    <h6 class="post-title">{{post.headline}}</h6>
                    <p class="post-intro">{{post.sub_headline}}</p>
                    <a href="{% url 'post' post.id %}">Read More</a>
                    <hr>
                    {% for tag in post.tags.all %}
                        <span class="tag">{{tag}}, </span>
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        {% empty %}
            <h3 align="center">No posts found...</h3>
        {% endfor %}

    </div>
</div>

{% endblock content %}
```

When I upload the images via the admin page, the images are successfully saved to **images folder** but I can't access the images in my **views.py**

Comment: First and foremost, check if the images work when you set debug = True (in settings.py)

Answer (score 1):

```
from django.conf import settings
img_path = "your_server_address" + settings.MEDIA_URL + unique_img
```

In case you are using localhost, this is how u can access the image. Here unique_path_to_image is the path that is stored in database and media_url_folder_name is what you provide in settings.py file.

http://127.0.0.1:8000/media_url_folder_name/unique_path_to_image

Comment: Thanks for the help but I don't really under what you mean by that.
Well, I can access the images using the normal method: <img src="{% static 'images/image.png' %}">
but when I try to use ImageField as shown above, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

**This is how you can show uploaded images by the user in the template**

1. **Set the MEDIA_URL variable in the project settings.py file**

   MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
2. **Add this directive to the project urls.py file**

   from django.conf.urls.static import static

   from django.conf import settings

   urlpatterns = [
   ...
   ]

   urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

Try it and let us know

Comment: Thanks @Rvector, I did that already,
the images can actually be accessed but the problem happened when I tried to Use ImageField.